# Sorting 2 lines at a time with sed

Tags: regex, sorting, sed

I would like to use `sed` to sort a large playlist file. Each playlist item has 2 lines so I need to sort based on the string after `tvg-name=` in the first line (so in this case line one would be **UK: Button 1(SG)**) sorting this first line and the following line with it (the one that begins with `http`).

I've seen very similar regex examples but the syntax is beyond me to reverse engineer to fit my file. Can anyone help?

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="BBCRedButton.uk" tvg-name="UK: BBC Red Button 1 (SG)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: BBC Red Button 1 (SG)
http://wesite.test:8080/live/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/112233.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="BBC1London.uk" tvg-name="UK: BBC ONE (HD) (720p)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: BBC ONE (HD) (720p)
http://wesite.test:8080/live/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/36011.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="BBC1Scotland.uk" tvg-name="UK: BBC One Scot FHD (1080p)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: BBC One Scot FHD (1080p)
http://wesite.test:8080/live/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/24651.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Act Of Grace" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/skQxxCIxEWuXL4tmPcfDoFjtSZU_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Act Of Grace
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/102408.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Act Of Valor" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/1Xcd5ci69pVXMPP02DU11Ffq0yY_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Act Of Valor
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/96873.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Action Jackson" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/rg5WY1SiyPDuTYZs2vgTV0csVbz_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Action Jackson
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/96874.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Acts Of Vengeance" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/r5o6vWPYOQs6bv91gQ8kQs2zQYl_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Acts Of Vengeance
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/107101.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Creed" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/hKzhV274pkZBSpXfCjUyzbyYKLl_small.jpg" group-title="Drama",Creed
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/102773.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Creep Van" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/r2tSTcns0gHVynnLVPwCtTePfOt_small.jpg" group-title="Horror",Creep Van
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/105306.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Creepozoids" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/gZ3HBNBYe6hDTsocsXjDYGv0ZXD_small.jpg" group-title="",Creepozoids
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/106831.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Creepshow 2" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/qxJWtBb89RaSRgLuz1d6ZuFTfVG_small.jpg" group-title="Horror",Creepshow 2
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/105307.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Acts Of Violence" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/pK9CugRd3DIP0THBH8WlGrvk5vy_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Acts Of Violence
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/96711.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Adaptation" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/5trb1V5f3IsjpZx2GiuUylowl3W_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Adaptation
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/99509.mp4
```

Expected Ouput :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="BBCRedButton.uk" tvg-name="UK: BBC Red Button 1 (SG)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: BBC Red Button 1 (SG)
http://wesite.test:8080/live/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/112233.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="BBC1London.uk" tvg-name="UK: BBC ONE (HD) (720p)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: BBC ONE (HD) (720p)
http://wesite.test:8080/live/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/36011.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="BBC1Scotland.uk" tvg-name="UK: BBC One Scot FHD (1080p)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: BBC One Scot FHD (1080p)
http://wesite.test:8080/live/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/24651.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Act Of Grace" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/skQxxCIxEWuXL4tmPcfDoFjtSZU_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Act Of Grace
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/102408.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Act Of Valor" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/1Xcd5ci69pVXMPP02DU11Ffq0yY_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Act Of Valor
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/96873.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Action Jackson" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/rg5WY1SiyPDuTYZs2vgTV0csVbz_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Action Jackson
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/96874.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Acts Of Vengeance" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/r5o6vWPYOQs6bv91gQ8kQs2zQYl_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Acts Of Vengeance
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/107101.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Acts Of Violence" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/pK9CugRd3DIP0THBH8WlGrvk5vy_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Acts Of Violence
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/96711.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Adaptation" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/5trb1V5f3IsjpZx2GiuUylowl3W_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Adaptation
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/99509.mp4   
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Creed" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/hKzhV274pkZBSpXfCjUyzbyYKLl_small.jpg" group-title="Drama",Creed
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/102773.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Creep Van" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/r2tSTcns0gHVynnLVPwCtTePfOt_small.jpg" group-title="Horror",Creep Van
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/105306.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Creepozoids" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/gZ3HBNBYe6hDTsocsXjDYGv0ZXD_small.jpg" group-title="",Creepozoids
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/106831.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Creepshow 2" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/qxJWtBb89RaSRgLuz1d6ZuFTfVG_small.jpg" group-title="Horror",Creepshow 2
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/105307.mp4
```

I copied and pasted a section of the movies from my master and neither of the scripts make a change to the output. Example Below :

Input :

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="The Santa Clause" tvg-logo="http://liquidit.info:8080/images/hrZjAYAF1o37k4Qb442c4yxwVLw_small.jpg" group-title=_Movies_",The Santa Clause
http://liquidit.info:8080/movie/Wallace47B/2IhPHmO9Q8/104987.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="The Santa Clause 2" tvg-logo="http://liquidit.info:8080/images/i7tbiDPIaa4VsQh1wWmbkY4zTRX_small.jpg" group-title=_Movies_",The Santa Clause 2
http://liquidit.info:8080/movie/Wallace47B/2IhPHmO9Q8/104988.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="The Santa Clause 3 The Escape Clause" tvg-logo="http://liquidit.info:8080/images/kvKXyrc3cUGqXin2u76Ef8lApMI_small.jpg" group-title=_Movies_",The Santa Clause 3 The Escape Clause
http://liquidit.info:8080/movie/Wallace47B/2IhPHmO9Q8/101023.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="The Sapphires" tvg-logo="http://liquidit.info:8080/images/h7zn7Sf0Jl6mFZjGj4TCHjSJj6T_small.jpg" group-title=_Movies_",The Sapphires
http://liquidit.info:8080/movie/Wallace47B/2IhPHmO9Q8/101024.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Fracture" tvg-logo="http://liquidit.info:8080/images/sl5QYze20MclzDLxLDqe3sEJdiW_small.jpg" group-title=_Movies_",Fracture
http://liquidit.info:8080/movie/Wallace47B/2IhPHmO9Q8/107279.mp4
```

Expected Ouptut would be the Movie Item "Fracture" at the top due to alpabeticalised sort.

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Fracture" tvg-logo="http://liquidit.info:8080/images/sl5QYze20MclzDLxLDqe3sEJdiW_small.jpg" group-title=_Movies_",Fracture
http://liquidit.info:8080/movie/Wallace47B/2IhPHmO9Q8/107279.mp4  
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="The Santa Clause" tvg-logo="http://liquidit.info:8080/images/hrZjAYAF1o37k4Qb442c4yxwVLw_small.jpg" group-title=_Movies_",The Santa Clause
http://liquidit.info:8080/movie/Wallace47B/2IhPHmO9Q8/104987.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="The Santa Clause 2" tvg-logo="http://liquidit.info:8080/images/i7tbiDPIaa4VsQh1wWmbkY4zTRX_small.jpg" group-title=_Movies_",The Santa Clause 2
http://liquidit.info:8080/movie/Wallace47B/2IhPHmO9Q8/104988.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="The Santa Clause 3 The Escape Clause" tvg-logo="http://liquidit.info:8080/images/kvKXyrc3cUGqXin2u76Ef8lApMI_small.jpg" group-title=_Movies_",The Santa Clause 3 The Escape Clause
http://liquidit.info:8080/movie/Wallace47B/2IhPHmO9Q8/101023.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="The Sapphires" tvg-logo="http://liquidit.info:8080/images/h7zn7Sf0Jl6mFZjGj4TCHjSJj6T_small.jpg" group-title=_Movies_",The Sapphires
http://liquidit.info:8080/movie/Wallace47B/2IhPHmO9Q8/101024.mp4
```

Comment: Explain why that would be the expected output given your posted sample input. "Acts of Violence" and "Adaptation" just jumped from the end of the input file to the middle of the output file - that's a lot more than just sorting the `_Movies_` records so explain how a program is supposed to know to make that happen. If all of the `_Movies_` records are supposed to end up grouped together, how should a program decide where to put that grouping in the output? Where the first _Movies_ were in the input or where most of the _Movies_ were or something else?

Comment: I hadnt realised the Creepozoids and Creepshow did not have group name _Movies_ (sorry).  What i am trying to do is sort alphabetically the lines that fall in the group name movies based on the string after tvg-name.

Comment: so one of the last 2 scripts I included in my answer does exactly what you want, right?

Comment: Hi ED - Both options dont seem to modify the script - Ive added a second example input and output in the post.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't keep peeling the onion on this. As you can see in my answer, the scripts I provided do convert the input you provided to the output you provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with a tool like sed, you must either A) have faith that your fields don't contain anything malignant like `tvg-id="http://...`, or B) write extremely painstaking scripts.

I would try something crude but effective, like this. First, combine two lines into one:

```
sed 'N;s/\n//'
```

Then copy the `tvg-name` field to the front of the line:

```
sed 's/\(.*tvg-name=\)\("[^"]*"\)/\2\1\2/'
```

Then sort:

```
sort
```

Then remove the field I'd added:

```
sed 's/^"[^"]*"//'
```

Then split the one line back into two:

```
sed 'h;s/http.*//;p;g;s/.*http/http/'
```

Putting it all together:

```
sed 'N;s/\n//;s/\(.*tvg-name=\)\("[^"]*"\)/\2\1\2/' filename | sort | sed 's/^"[^"]*"//;h;s/http.*//;p;g;s/.*http/http/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & sort):

```
sed 'N;s/^\(.*\)\n/\1\1/;2h;2!H;$!d;x;s/.*/echo '\''&'\'' | sort -k3,3/e;s/^\(.*\)\1/\1\n/Mg' file
```

Convert each two line record into a single line by duplicating the first line and removing the newline between the first and second lines. Gather the entire file up into memory held in the hold space. At the end of file, swap to the hold space and using GNU sed's evaluate command as a flag in the substitution command, sort the file on the third field in the single line record. Reformat the single line record back into a two line record and print the results.

Comment: Hi neither answer seems to work. The sort does not work seem to alphabeticalise the rows. Also when I split the lines again the file is only half the size.

Comment: @johnWallace I left an extra command in by mistake and forgot to quote the echo command properly. If I use your (short) data, to my eyes, does as you wished, but I am only guessing. Perhaps  you could provide more data before/after.

Comment: Hi Potongget  I get "sed: bad option in substitution expression" when executing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Without better sample input and the expected output it's a guess but this might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS='\t' 'NF>1{key=$4; cnt=0} {print key, ++cnt, $0}' file | sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 -k2,2n -s | cut -f3-
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Button.uk" tvg-name="UK: Button 1 (SG)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: Button 1 (SG)
#http://website.info:8080/live/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/112233.ts
##EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="London.uk" tvg-name="UK: London (HD) (720p)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: London (HD) (720p)
#http://website.info:8080/live/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/36011.ts
```

or if you wanted it sorted in reverse:

```
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS='\t' 'NF>1{key=$4; cnt=0} {print key, ++cnt, $0}' file | sort -t$'\t' -k1,1r -k2,2n -s | cut -f3-
##EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="London.uk" tvg-name="UK: London (HD) (720p)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: London (HD) (720p)
#http://website.info:8080/live/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/36011.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Button.uk" tvg-name="UK: Button 1 (SG)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: Button 1 (SG)
#http://website.info:8080/live/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/112233.ts
```

It just prefixes each line with the key value from between the quotes followed by a count of the lines starting at that value, then sorts it by those added fields, then removes the added fields again. It's easiest to understand if you look at how it works in stages:

**1) Add the 2 prefix fields to be used for sorting:**

```
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS='\t' 'NF>1{key=$4; cnt=0} {print key, ++cnt, $0}' file
UK: Button 1 (SG)       1       #EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Button.uk" tvg-name="UK: Button 1 (SG)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: Button 1 (SG)
UK: Button 1 (SG)       2       #http://website.info:8080/live/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/112233.ts
UK: London (HD) (720p)  1       ##EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="London.uk" tvg-name="UK: London (HD) (720p)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: London (HD) (720p)
UK: London (HD) (720p)  2       #http://website.info:8080/live/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/36011.ts
```

**2) Sort the output using the 2 fields added at step 1:**

```
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS='\t' 'NF>1{key=$4; cnt=0} {print key, ++cnt, $0}' file |
    sort -t$'\t' -k1,1r -k2,2n -s
UK: London (HD) (720p)  1       ##EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="London.uk" tvg-name="UK: London (HD) (720p)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: London (HD) (720p)
UK: London (HD) (720p)  2       #http://website.info:8080/live/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/36011.ts
UK: Button 1 (SG)       1       #EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Button.uk" tvg-name="UK: Button 1 (SG)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: Button 1 (SG)
UK: Button 1 (SG)       2       #http://website.info:8080/live/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/112233.ts
```

**3) Remove the 2 fields added at step 1:**

```
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS='\t' 'NF>1{key=$4; cnt=0} {print key, ++cnt, $0}' file |
    sort -t$'\t' -k1,1r -k2,2n -s |
    cut -f3-
##EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="London.uk" tvg-name="UK: London (HD) (720p)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: London (HD) (720p)
#http://website.info:8080/live/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/36011.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Button.uk" tvg-name="UK: Button 1 (SG)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: Button 1 (SG)
#http://website.info:8080/live/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/112233.ts
```

Note that the above will work for any number of lines in multi-line blocks and the same approach works for sorting on multiple different substrings. It's also very efficient (stores almost nothing in memory) and easy to debug/enhance/maintain later.

**Edit 1:**
Based on your comments below and the new sample input you provided the following MY be what you want but I don't know if it is or not since the didn't provide the expected output and best I can tell the sample input you provided is already sorted so there's no way to tell if the tool is doing anything at all.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS  = "\""
    OFS = "\t"
}
/^#/ {
    tvgName        = $4
    nameRowNr      = 0
    prevGroupTitle = groupTitle
    groupTitle     = $8
    if ( ! ((groupTitle == "_Movies_") && (groupTitle == prevGroupTitle)) ) {
        groupNr++
    }
}
{
    print groupNr, tvgName, ++nameRowNr, $0
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -t$'\t' -k1,1n -k2,2 -k3,3n -s | cut -f4-
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="BBCRedButton.uk" tvg-name="UK: BBC Red Button 1 (SG)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: BBC Red Button 1 (SG)
http://wesite.test:8080/live/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/112233.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="BBC1London.uk" tvg-name="UK: BBC ONE (HD) (720p)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: BBC ONE (HD) (720p)
http://wesite.test:8080/live/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/36011.ts
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="BBCRedButton.uk" tvg-name="UK: BBC Red Button 1 (SG)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: BBC Red Button 1 (SG)
http://wesite.test:8080/live/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/112233.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="BBC1London.uk" tvg-name="UK: BBC ONE (HD) (720p)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: BBC ONE (HD) (720p)
http://wesite.test:8080/live/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/36011.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="BBC1Scotland.uk" tvg-name="UK: BBC One Scot FHD (1080p)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: BBC One Scot FHD (1080p)
http://wesite.test:8080/live/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/24651.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Act Of Grace" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/skQxxCIxEWuXL4tmPcfDoFjtSZU_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Act Of Grace
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/102408.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Act Of Valor" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/1Xcd5ci69pVXMPP02DU11Ffq0yY_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Act Of Valor
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/96873.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Action Jackson" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/rg5WY1SiyPDuTYZs2vgTV0csVbz_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Action Jackson
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/96874.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Acts Of Vengeance" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/r5o6vWPYOQs6bv91gQ8kQs2zQYl_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Acts Of Vengeance
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/107101.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Acts Of Violence" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/pK9CugRd3DIP0THBH8WlGrvk5vy_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Acts Of Violence
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/96711.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Adaptation" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/5trb1V5f3IsjpZx2GiuUylowl3W_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Adaptation
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/99509.mp4
```

**Edit 2:**
Given the updated sample input and expected output now posted in your question, this may be what you want instead:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS  = "\""
    OFS = "\t"
}
/^#/ {
    tvgName        = $4
    nameRowNr      = 0
    groupTitle     = $8
    if ( groupTitle == "_Movies_" ) {
        if ( !(groupTitle in groupTitle2nr) ) {
            groupTitle2nr[groupTitle] = ++numGroups
        }
        groupNr = groupTitle2nr[groupTitle]
    }
    else {
        groupNr = ++numGroups
    }
}
{
    print groupNr, tvgName, ++nameRowNr, $0
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -t$'\t' -k1,1n -k2,2 -k3,3n -s | cut -f4-
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="BBCRedButton.uk" tvg-name="UK: BBC Red Button 1 (SG)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: BBC Red Button 1 (SG)
http://wesite.test:8080/live/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/112233.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="BBC1London.uk" tvg-name="UK: BBC ONE (HD) (720p)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: BBC ONE (HD) (720p)
http://wesite.test:8080/live/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/36011.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="BBC1Scotland.uk" tvg-name="UK: BBC One Scot FHD (1080p)" tvg-logo="" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT & LIFESTYLE UK",UK: BBC One Scot FHD (1080p)
http://wesite.test:8080/live/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/24651.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Act Of Grace" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/skQxxCIxEWuXL4tmPcfDoFjtSZU_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Act Of Grace
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/102408.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Act Of Valor" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/1Xcd5ci69pVXMPP02DU11Ffq0yY_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Act Of Valor
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/96873.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Action Jackson" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/rg5WY1SiyPDuTYZs2vgTV0csVbz_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Action Jackson
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/96874.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Acts Of Vengeance" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/r5o6vWPYOQs6bv91gQ8kQs2zQYl_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Acts Of Vengeance
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/107101.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Acts Of Violence" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/pK9CugRd3DIP0THBH8WlGrvk5vy_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Acts Of Violence
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/96711.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Adaptation" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/5trb1V5f3IsjpZx2GiuUylowl3W_small.jpg" group-title="_Movies_",Adaptation
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/99509.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Creed" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/hKzhV274pkZBSpXfCjUyzbyYKLl_small.jpg" group-title="Drama",Creed
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/102773.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Creep Van" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/r2tSTcns0gHVynnLVPwCtTePfOt_small.jpg" group-title="Horror",Creep Van
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/105306.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Creepozoids" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/gZ3HBNBYe6hDTsocsXjDYGv0ZXD_small.jpg" group-title="",Creepozoids
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/106831.mp4
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Creepshow 2" tvg-logo="http://wesite.test:8080/images/qxJWtBb89RaSRgLuz1d6ZuFTfVG_small.jpg" group-title="Horror",Creepshow 2
http://wesite.test:8080/movie/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/105307.mp4
```

The above script is slightly more complicated than it has to be so it'd be trivial for you to add additional "group-title"s to sort on all in the same invocation of the tool if/when you need to do that in future by just tweaking the `if ( groupTitle == "_Movies_" )` line.

Comment: Hi Ed, - Your script almost works with my full file. Sorry for being a pain, im very new to scripting so trying to pick this up as I go. Is it possible to post a full file for you to check (if you have time?). I would like to sort A-Z all the titles in the _Movies_ group title (to make matters more complex)

Comment: Ed - Sorry by joined file I mean the combined lines that another user suggested. I dont think its relevant to your script?

Comment: John - no, you have to create a [mcve] in your question with whatever variations of the input you want us to consider. See [ask] if it's not clear. As a start - it sounds like you've discovered 1 or more entries in your full file that my script doesn't work for, presumably because it doesn't follow the same format as your existing entries, so add that to the example in your input and any others that fail and are obviously different in format from each other. And no, it doesn't sound like the "joined file" has anything to do with my script.

Comment: Hi Ed,  Ive updated the script at the top to cover Minimal, Complete and Verifiable. Thanks for your help. The script now has 2 groups and I want to sort only the group called group-title "_Movies_". (Movies has underscore either side)

Comment: You forgot to add the expected output, please do that to complete the [mcve] and avoid any misunderstanding. Right now I don't even know if you want the non-Movies group to be output or discarded or what, nor am I sure what you want the Movies group to be sorted on.

Comment: I added a modified script at the end of my answer but I don't know if it's doing what you want or not since you didn't provide the expected output and best I can tell the input is already sorted so the script could be doing `cat file` and produce the same output so best we can say is it's not producing wrong output (if I understood what you want correctly).

Comment: Given your updated input/output I posted an updated solution. I am just guessing at your requirements now though so please update your question to state what they are.